# Recursive Definition Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recursion

I found two versions of a theorem which guarantees that recursive defined functions do exist (or that recursive definitions do make sense).

The first is:

*Given a function $f:X\to X$ and an element $a \in X$there exists a unique function $F: \mathbb{N} \to X$ such that $F(0) = a$ and $F(n+1)=f(F(n))$*

The other one is:

*Given $n$ ($\in \mathbb{N} \backslash \{ 0\}$) functions $V_n: X^n \to X $ there exists a unique function $F: \mathbb{N} \to X$ such that $F(0) = a$ and $F(n+1) = V_{n+1}(F(0), F(1), ..., F(n))$*.

I don't get the intuition for this. I know what the purpose basically is: to have a recursively constructing definition or so, but what is the intention to define $F$ in one or the other way? I guess you get that element $a$ in $X$ and than start "hopping around" in a certain order.

How does it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: beware of typos $f$ versus $F$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two definitions correspond to the fact that when defining a recursive function, you can either make it depend only on the last value, or on all smaller values and on $n$.

In fact the first definition is very retrictive, because it means that you can just look at the last value and deduce the current one, without even knowing $n$.

For instance for factorial, this is not enough information, you have $f(0)=1$ and $f(n)=nf(n-1)$. In particular $f(0)=f(1)$ but $f(1)\neq f(2)$, so $f$ cannot depend only on the last value.

A case where you can use the first definition is for the Collatz function for instance, or for $f(n)=2^n$.

Comment: Thanks for this. But what about just defining the factorial for 0 and 1 and from this point recursively? I mean, you only depend on the last value. Is there an example for a function that depends on all of the preceding ones or at least on "many"?

Comment: There is no simple formula going from the last factorial value to the current one. You can always write the complete list $f(2)=6$, $f(6)=24$, and so on, but that's not the spirit of recursive definitions.

Comment: What I tried to say was that you could take that $f(n) = nf(n-1)$, if you take extra care for 0 and 1.

Comment: Yes but this does not fit your first definition: $f$ is not allowed to depend on $n$. you don't need extra care with this formula, it works well in all cases, with $0$ base case.

Comment: So the point is that the definition of factorial f(n+1) depends on _both_ (n+1) _and_ f(n)? And in case of Collatz, multiplying by 2 does not depend on the parameter.

Comment: yes that's the point

Comment: Would it be possible to expand on why the first theorem isn't strong enough to define the factorial function? My textbook, which proves the *second* version of the theorem  still defines the factorial function via $f(0) = 1$ and $f(n+1) = (n+1)f(n)$ such that I don't quite see how that definition couldn't work with the first version. If I call $g(n) = 2^n$ your example, I have $g(0) = 1$ and $g(n+1) = 2*g(n)$ too?

Comment: Ah I *think* I see now. In the first definition given by OP, our $f$ is fixed and so I cannot write $F(n+1) = f(F(n)) = (n+1)F(n)$ as I might want to, whereas with the *sequence* of functions $V_n$ I do have that freedom. In contrast, with the $2^n$ function if I fix $g(x) = 2x$, then $F(n+1) = g(F(n)) = g(2^n) = 22^n = 2^{n+1}$ is no problem.

Comment: That is, with respect to factorials the relevant property we use is that we have a sequence of functions (we "use their subscripts" as it were), rather than that there are $n$ arguments to $V_n$ (but as you point out, there are perhaps contexts when that might be useful too)?